# Callback from External OAUTH in Django

Tags: python, django, oauth

Alrighty. Setup information - Django 1.8.3, Python 2.7.3, using Goodreads 0.2.4 api handler for Python (slightly modified). I'm at the point where Goodreads does a callback to the app, but the clickjacker middleware is catching it as an error and tossing out a 404. If I disable the clickjacker prevention (which I'd prefer not to do), I get an "argument of type 'type' is not iterable" error.

Relevant Code:

```
from goodreads import client

grClient = client.GoodreadsClient(<key>,<other_key>)

def goodReadsOAUTH_stage1(request,user):
    try:
       return HttpResponseRedirect(grClient.authenticate()) 
       # function modified to return the URL rather than open a browser
    except keyError:
        return Http404

def goodReadsOAUTH_stage2(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.GET['authorize'] == 1:
            grRecord = goodreadsOAUTHKeys(request.user,request.GET['oauth_token']
            grRecord.save()
            grClient.session.oauth_finalize()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(request,'workroom:profile',kwargs={'user':request.user.username}))
        else:
            return Http404
    else:
        return Http404
```

And the URLconf for the two:

```
    url(r'^social/(?P<user>[-\w\d]+)/goodreads/OAUTH/$', views.goodReadsOAUTH_stage1, name='goodreads-oauth-one'),
    url(r'^social/goodreads/OAUTH/validation/$', views.goodReadsOAUTH_stage2, name='goodreads-oauth-two'),
```

And the ensuing error message!

> type object 'Http404' has no attribute 'get'
>
> Exception Location:   /home/.../public/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py in process_response, line 31

And that line of code from the clickjacking protection:

```
 if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:
```

I'm essentially at a loss here as to how to get the callback to function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Http404 wrong. Http404 is an Exception, use it like

```
raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
```

For the reference [see](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/) section "Returning Errors"

Comment: Thanks! That got me to where I'm getting errors that make sense for debugging.